# Modelling sets of cartesian products in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to model some specific sets (`Ensembles`) of elements that
are themselves Ensembles.

All the "inner" Ensembles are the cartesian products of two sets taken
from some other sets of sets (W1 and W2), and I want to show that if
(a,b) and (c,d) are in the cartesian product, then (a, d) and (c, b)
are also in the product.

I'm using Coq's `Ensembles` which express sets as predicates, but in
my case it's also OK to assume that sets are equal if they contain the
same elements, and that terms are either in or not in the sets 
(which is not the case for all such sets in constructive logic...)

I have problems finishing the proof, as I seem to be losing some
information, and would be grateful for any help.

First some definitions:

```
Require Import Ensembles.

Variables T1 T2:Type.
(* S1 and S2 are two "container" sets for the left and right elements,
   but I'm not doing the cartesian product of S1 and S2 but of
   some subsets of S1 and S2, (see W1 and W2 below) 
*)
Variables (S1: Ensemble T1) (S2:Ensemble T2).


Notation "a ∈ A" := (In _ A a) (at level 50).
Notation "a === b" := (Same_set _ a b) (at level 50).

Hypothesis S1dec: forall x, x ∈ S1 \/ ~ x ∈ S1.
Hypothesis S2dec: forall y, y ∈ S2 \/ ~ y ∈ S2.

Variables (W1 : Ensemble (Ensemble T1)).
Variables (W2 : Ensemble (Ensemble T2)).

Hypothesis W1_closed: forall A B, A === B -> A ∈ W1 -> B ∈ W1.
Hypothesis W2_closed: forall A B, A === B -> A ∈ W2 -> B ∈ W2.

Hypothesis W1_in_S1: forall w, w ∈ W1 -> Included _ w S1.
Hypothesis W2_in_S2: forall w, w ∈ W2 -> Included _ w S2.

(* extract the elements on the left or right "side" of the product set *)
Definition projL (w:Ensemble (T1*T2)) := fun x => exists y, (x,y) ∈ w.
Definition projR (w:Ensemble (T1*T2)) := fun y => exists x, (x,y) ∈ w.
```

The cartesian products are made from members of the sets `W1` and `W2`.

```
(* The definition of the product set. The members are those
sets whose both left and right projection are in W1 and W2 *)
Definition prodW1W2 : Ensemble (Ensemble (T1*T2)) :=
  fun (S:Ensemble (T1*T2)) =>
     projL S ∈ W1 /\ projR S ∈ W2.
```

Maybe useful to know...?

```
Lemma projL_closed: forall A B , A === B -> projL A === projL B.
Proof.  firstorder. Qed.
Lemma projR_closed: forall A B , A === B -> projR A === projR B.
Proof.  firstorder. Qed.
```

Here is the theorem I'd like to prove:

```
Theorem all_pairs_are_in_the_product:
    forall WW, WW ∈ prodW1W2 ->
          forall x y, (x, y) ∈ WW ->
                 forall z w, (z, w) ∈ WW ->
                        (x, w) ∈ WW.
Proof.
  intros WW (H1 & H2 ) x y Hxy z w Hzw.

  assert (WW === (fun x => let (a,b) := x in a ∈ projL WW /\ b ∈ projR WW)).
  {
    split; intros [a b] Hx.
    - eexists; eauto; firstorder.
    - destruct Hx; firstorder.
      (* This is where I'm stuck *)
    admit.
  }

  enough ((x, w) ∈ (fun x : T1 * T2 => let (a, b) := x in a ∈ projL WW /\ b ∈ projR WW))
  as [Ha Hb] by firstorder.

  firstorder.
Admitted.
```

How the types and set are intended to go together:
[image: How the types and set are intended to go together]

Comment: I'm not sure I see the resemblance with cartesian products. If `W1 = W2 = {{1, 2}}`, then `{(1,1), (2,2)}` is in `prodW1W2` and that contradicts the theorem.

Comment: Thanks, yes there seems to be a problem with the definition of `prodW1W2` as your example shows.

Comment: I'll try again with this definition: `Definition prodW1W2 : Ensemble (Ensemble (T1*T2)) :=
  fun (S:Ensemble (T1*T2)) =>
    exists w1 w2, w1 ∈ W1 /\ w2 ∈ W2 /\
             forall a b, (a,b) ∈ S <-> (a ∈ w1 /\ b ∈ w2).`

Comment: Now the proof is `intros WW (w1 & w2 & Hw1 & Hw2 & Hww).
  intros.
  apply Hww.
  firstorder.`  Thanks for the help @Li-yao Xia !

Comment: You're welcome!